# Why do I get a change in the Ruby version path on "bundle install --deployment"?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've been stuck with weird Ruby version issues for a long time. It is changing from Ruby 1.9.3 to 2.0.0 to 1.9.1 continuously.

Initially I was getting the error:

```
Rails: cannot load such file — safe_yaml/transform/to_symbol (LoadError)
```

as I asked about in "[Rails: cannot load such file -- safe_yaml/transform/to_symbol (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772142/rails-cannot-load-such-file-safe-yaml-transform-to-symbol-loaderror)".

Then I followed the tutorial: "[cannot load such file — safe_yaml](http://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/cannot-load-such-file-safe_yaml-rails_admin/)".

When I ran this command on my server:

```
 bundle install – -deployment
```

It wiped my Ruby 1.9.3 and changed all default paths to 1.9.1. Also, now the Ruby1.9.3 folder doesn't contain gems.

I am really clueless as things get messier. Can somebody please help me out of this?

My rvm -v o/p is:

```
rvm 1.21.12 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Comment: Are you using `RVM` or `rbenv`? They're ruby version managers that allow for multiple versions of Ruby to be installed and used for different projects. Try `rvm -v` or `rbenv -v` at a prompt and update the question with the results.

Comment: It's normal for ruby 1.9.3 to install gems in a folder with 1.9.1 in the path

Comment: First off: bundler will never delete your rubies. What the `bundle install -- -development` does is install your gems into a specific folder, based on your ruby-version. Which version of `safe-yaml` do you have installed? Do you also use `rails_admin` from git? Do you have a `Gemfile.lock` file? From the comments on the blogpost, you should be using safe-yaml version 0.9.3 --> is that the version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was problem with safe_yaml version.

I have rails-admin 0.4.9. For this, safe_yaml 0.6.3 is required where rails_admin 0.4.9 installs safe_yaml 0.9.4.

So i included safe_yaml 0.6.3 in my gemfile separately and removed safe_yaml 0.6.4.

And everything worked!!

Thank everyone for help.